# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied) AND Cast Issue

Tags: java, jdbc, java-io

When I am trying to save/update a file, I am getting the following errors

1/Error1: When I m trying to Update my User information , it appears this issue

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("image");
InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file
if (filePart != null) {
    // prints out some information for debugging
    System.out.println(filePart.getName());
    System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
    System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());
    inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
}
// String image = request.getParameter("image");
CandidatDAO dao = new CandidatDAO();
Part part = request.getPart("image");
String filename = extractFileName(part);
String save_path = File.separator +filename ;
File filesaveDir = new File(save_path);
part.write(save_path+File.separator);

String filePath = save_path+File.separator+filename;

dao.Update(new Candidat(id,nom,prenom,naiss,cin,sexe,nat,email,adresse,tel, (Blob) inputStream,login,mdp));

ArrayList list = dao.FindAll();
ServletContext cn = request.getServletContext();
cn.setAttribute("liste", list);
response.sendRedirect("ListeCandidat.jsp");
```

2/Error2: When i m trying to save a file

```
Part part = request.getPart("image");
String filename = extractFileName(part);
String save_path = "D:\\Examtp(2)\\Examtp\\web\\imagesF\\"+File.separator +filename;
// String save_path = "D:\\Master2017-2018\\JEE\\TP\\Examtp\\web\\imagesF\\"+File.separator +filename ;
File filesaveDir = new File(save_path);
part.write(save_path+File.separator);

String filePath = save_path+File.separator+filename;
FormateurDAO dao = new FormateurDAO();
dao.Add(new Formateur(nom,prenom,naiss,cin,sexe,nat,email,adresse,tel,filename,login,mdp));

//  ArrayList list = dao.FindAll();
ServletContext cn = request.getServletContext();
cn.setAttribute("cin", cin);
response.sendRedirect("AjouterDiplome.jsp");
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need `fileSaveDir.mkdirs()` before saving the file. `File fileSaveDir = new File(...)` by itself does nothing on the disk.
2. Don't ask multiple questions in a single post.